# Python Pandas format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I was making a comparation using pandas and I found the next problem:

I have 2 tables like this:

```
  DESCRIPTION   EXTRAS   ADDRESS  AVAILABLE
1   House        WiFi     CP 432     1
2   Farm         NONE     CP 345     1
3   House        Wifi     CP 315     1

  DESCRIPTION   EXTRAS   ADDRESS  AVAILABLE
1   House        WiFi     CP 437     0
2   House        Wifi     CP 315     0
```

And I have the next output:

```
ID   DESCRIPTION   EXTRAS   ADDRESS  AVAILABLE
1,1   House        WiFi     CP 432     1
2,2   Farm         NONE     CP 345     1
3,3   House        Wifi     CP 315     1
4,1   House        WiFi     CP 437     0
```

Is like pandas is mixing both ID´s.

On the other hand in another CSV, I found that some lines looks great, but the others have all the information in the "ID" column. The strange thing is that before the merge of the two CSVs all the info is perfectly placed in the correct column. It looks like this:

```
ID   DESCRIPTION   EXTRAS   ADDRESS  AVAILABLE
1   House        WiFi     CP 432     1
2;Farm NONE CP 345 1
3   House        Wifi     CP 315     1
1   House        WiFi     CP 437     0
```

The code that merged the 2 CSV´s in both situations is this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv(get_work_folder_path(args.processName) + "/" + args.processName +"EnAlquiler"+ ".csv" , error_bad_lines=False)
df2 = pd.read_csv(get_work_folder_path(args.processName) + "/" + args.processName + ".csv" , error_bad_lines=False)

frames = [df1, df2]
result = pd.concat(frames)

df5 = pd.DataFrame(result)
df5.drop_duplicates( keep='first', inplace = True)

df5.to_csv(get_work_folder_path(args.processName) + "/" + args.processName +"HomeAwayComparacion"+ ".csv")

print(df5)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that one of your CSV inputs isn't properly formatted. If it won't work without error_bad_lines=False that kinda proves it. Try to just open and export the csv files before combining them. If I am correct you'll see the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try append function:

```
str1 = io.StringIO('''
DESCRIPTION;EXTRAS;ADDRESS;AVAILABLE
1;House;WiFi;CP 432;1
2;Farm;NONE;CP 345;1
3;House;Wifi;CP 315;1
''')
df1 = pd.read_csv(str1, sep=";")

str2 = io.StringIO('''
DESCRIPTION;EXTRAS;ADDRESS;AVAILABLE
1;House;WiFi;CP 437;0
2;House;Wifi;CP 325;0
''')
df2 = pd.read_csv(str2, sep=";")

ddf = df1.append(df2)
print(ddf)
```

Output:

```
  DESCRIPTION EXTRAS ADDRESS  AVAILABLE
1       House   WiFi  CP 432          1
2        Farm   NONE  CP 345          1
3       House   Wifi  CP 315          1
1       House   WiFi  CP 437          0
2       House   Wifi  CP 325          0
```

If you want to give new index numbers, use `ignore_index=True` option:

```
ddf = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
print(ddf)

  DESCRIPTION EXTRAS ADDRESS  AVAILABLE
0       House   WiFi  CP 432          1
1        Farm   NONE  CP 345          1
2       House   Wifi  CP 315          1
3       House   WiFi  CP 437          0
4       House   Wifi  CP 325          0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your importation and type of df1 and df2. 
Check index in your dataframe and if necessary, use "df.reset_index()"

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1","2","3"],
                   "DESCRIPTION" : ["House","Farm","House"],
                   "EXTRAS" : ["Wifi", None, "Wifi"],
                   "ADDRESS" : ["CP 432","CP 345","CP 315"],
                   "AVAILABLE" : [1,1,1]},
                   index = ["1","2","3"]
                  )
df2 =pd.DataFrame({"ID" : ["1","2"],
                   "DESCRIPTION" : ["House","House"],
                   "EXTRAS" : ["Wifi", "Wifi"],
                   "ADDRESS" : ["CP 432","CP 315"],
                   "AVAILABLE" : [0,0]},
                   index = [1,2]
                  )
frames = [df1, df2]
result=pd.concat(frames)
print(result)
df5 = pd.DataFrame(result)
df5.drop_duplicates( keep='first', inplace = True)
print(df5)
```

Result :

```
   ADDRESS  AVAILABLE DESCRIPTION EXTRAS ID
1  CP 432          1       House   Wifi  1
2  CP 345          1        Farm   None  2
3  CP 315          1       House   Wifi  3
1  CP 432          0       House   Wifi  1
2  CP 315          0       House   Wifi  2
```